# Simple WinForms GUI application not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a simple GUI with a button and two text boxes. I wrote the following code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hello ";
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this code and click `button1`, nothing happens; no message is displayed. Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Does your button's click event is set to button1_click method?

Comment: Are you binding the button's click event to the button1_Click method anywhere else in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link the button's click event to the method that will handle it.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button1.Click += button1_Click;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hello ";
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two options to resolve your issue:

1. Set event handler in Designer to your `button1`.
2. Add the following line to your code behind:

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       button1.Click += button1_Click; // <-- Add this line
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Check  InitializeComponent() method to see if the click event was set for button1.
You should se something like this

```
 this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

If you don't see it then you could either add it manualy to the code bellow InitializeComponent() or double click the button in design mode and the UI will do it for you in InitializeComponent() method.